# Show message to user in Xamarin API

Tags: c#, json, api, xamarin, xamarin.forms

You have an API (NOT modifiable) which you want to consume, this API receives some parameters which if they are NOT properly validated, the API throws a message of the error, it is precisely this message that I want to capture, for example here in the image I pass an erroneous password and want to show that message to the user.

[image: Postman]

For this, create a class called Response, which is responsible for managing the different calls made to the API

Response.cs:

```
 public class Response
    {
        public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }

        public string Message { get; set; }

        public object Result { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "userMessage")]
        public string userMessage { get; set; }
    }
```

in my LoginViewModel I call the method that this API consumes, which is implemented in a class called ApiService.cs:

ApiService.cs:

```
  public async Task<Response> GetLogin(
            string urlAPILogin, string KeyLogin, string Rut, string Password)
            {
                try
                {
                    var client = new HttpClient();
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(urlAPILogin);
                    string url = string.Format("login/index/?k=" + KeyLogin + "&rut=" + Rut + "&password=" + Password);
                    var response = await client.GetAsync(url);

                    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(result);

                    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        return new Response
                        {
                            IsSuccess = false,
                            Message = response.StatusCode.ToString(),
                            Result = model,
                        };
                    }

                    return new Response
                    {
                        IsSuccess = true,
                        Message = "Ok",
                        Result = model,
                    };

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return new Response
                    {
                        IsSuccess = false,
                        Message = ex.Message,
                    };
                }
            }
```

Now it is in my ViewModel (LoginViewModel) where I want to paint that message! and I try to capture it in the following way:

```
  var response = await apiService.GetLogin(
                urlAPILogin,
                KeyLogin,
                Rut,
                Password);


            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.userMessage))
            {                
                IsRunning = false;
                IsEnabled = true;
                await dialogService.ShowMessage(
                    "Error",
                    response.userMessage);
                Password = null;
                return;
            }
```

but I'm not getting the expected response (he paints the blank message to me !!!)

[image: screenshoot]

being that the object if it brings the message !!

[image: VS2017]

any help for me?
what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `LoginViewModel` method where you are awaiting the response, the variable with the `userMessage` you want is located a layer deeper.

**Currently:**

```
// userMessage is null in your *locals* section
await dialogService.ShowMessage("Error", response.userMessage);
```

**Should be:**

```
// This is where the wanted value is: userMessage is the desired message
await dialogService.ShowMessage("Error", response.Result.userMessage);
```

You will need to cast your `response.Result` as a Response since your Result variable is an **object**, but this should fix your problem.

**Should be (casted):**

```
// This is where the wanted value is: userMessage is the desired message
await dialogService.ShowMessage("Error", (response.Result as Response)?.userMessage);
```

Comment: but how do I cast the object? his answer gives me the following error: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'userMessage' and no accessible extension method 'userMessage' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found @TaylorD

Comment: Edited my answer to show the way to cast the object to your `Response` object.